# First steps with Python and scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, error-handling, scikit-learn, export

I believe I have a simple if not trivial question. I have a background in statistics and I tend to use Stata and R quite a bit. I am interested in learning Python. I used it for a while now and recently came into contact with scikit-learn.

I am trying to reproduce a simple example I got from google.

```
#the good old iris data
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .5)


#let's learn a little
from sklearn import tree
nordan_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = nordan_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = nordan_tree.predict(X_test)


#accuracy score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))

#print tree
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
     f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
import os
os.unlink('iris.dot')
```

The code runs smoothly - but where do I find my iris.pdf?

Comment: Did you install [`Graphviz`](http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php) so as to use it's `dot` tool to create a PDF file? You could also follow [`this documentation`](https://scikitlearn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) which takes you through the entire process.

Comment: i installed it via `pip install graphvidz`  - was that right?

Comment: I think you need to install `graphviz` separately if you need to use it's internal `dot` facility. Then you could do `$ dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf` from the terminal itself to create the pdf file.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification

Comment: Thanks! Works now!!